# gcc check if file is main (#if __BASE_FILE__ == __FILE__)

Tags: c, gcc, macros

In ruby there's very common idiom to check if current file is "main" file:

```
  if __FILE__ == $0
    # do something here (usually run unit tests)
  end
```

I'd like to do something similar in *C* after reading gcc documentation I've figured that it should work like this:

```
  #if __FILE__ == __BASE_FILE__
    // Do stuff
  #endif
```

the only problem is after I try this:

```
$ gcc src/bitmap_index.c -std=c99 -lm && ./a.out 
src/bitmap_index.c:173:1: error: token ""src/bitmap_index.c"" is not valid in preprocessor expressions
```

Am I using #if wrong?

As summary for future guests:

- You cannot compare string using #if
- **BASE_FILE** is the name of file that is being compiled (that Is actually what I wanted).
- Best way to do this is to set flag during compilation with -D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in gcc you can use:

#if __INCLUDE_LEVEL__ == 0

or:

if(!__INCLUDE_LEVEL__)

to check if your inside the __BASE_FILE__

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you are misusing `#if`. It only works on integer constant expressions. But even if you were using `if`, comparing pointers for equality is never a valid way to compare strings in C.

Comment: ok, I didn't find information that you can only compare ints with #if. pointer comparison will not yield equality. Any idea's how to work around that?

Comment: You could add `-DIN_BASE` on the command line for compiling the base file and use `#ifdef IN_BASE`. Or you could just stop trying to use Ruby idioms in C. Do you try to force English idioms into French if you speak French?

Comment: @Marcin: no, there isn't a simple way around the fact that the C preprocessor works with numbers only.  (The hard way around it pre-preprocesses the source with a different preprocessor, such as m4.)  What is the significance to you of 'the main file'?  What could be different about the code you write in the main file compared with anything else?

Comment: @Marcin: in some of my (older) programs, I have `#define MAIN_PROGRAM` at the top of the file containing the `main()` function for a program.  Any of my headers which contain `#ifdef MAIN_PROGRAM / char header_name_h[] = "@(#)header.h 1.6 1995-07-08 13:54:26"; / #endif` then leave their version information embedded in the object file.  However, that technique doesn't jibe well with modern VCS (such as Clearcase, Git, SVN, ...) so I'm not using it in new code.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: you are mistaken of what Marcin considers as a "main file". In ruby/python, all sources files can be run, and the "main file" is the file specified on the command line. files can depends on other files, and when they are included as a dependecy, they are not "the main file". the ruby trick is used to check if this file is used as a dependency or as a main file. This is not transposable in C, because in C, every file are to be compiled.

Comment: @BatchyX: yes, I understand that - and the only easy way of transferring the idea of 'main file' from Ruby to C is to use 'the file that contains the `main()` function' as the 'main file' (or the file that contains the Windows analog of `main()`).  Anything else makes even less sense.  And there's no automatic way to detect that file.  And I've yet to see a cogent explanation for why a C program would need the information - though I gave an illustration of how I used to use the information.

Comment: The idea was precisly to have multiple main() functions, If I compile root project file with all dependencies I use normal main file. If I compile just one file, then then main() from that file should be used.
I've seen this pattern but almost all of them used flags - like TESTING see http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/browser/tags/varnish-2.1.4/varnish-cache/lib/libvarnish/binary_heap.c
I thought that maybe I can skip setting that flag. But I'll just use it

Comment: @Marcin: What you're asking for can be done on most targets gcc supports by defining each file's `main` function (except the real one) as a weak symbol. As for whether you should do this, the answer is of course no. It's horribly non-standard and will waste space even in production builds. Instead just use a `-DTEST` or similar to build the unit test `main` functions.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you can't.

Alternatively, it works perfectly fine on a regular if condition, and gcc can optimize this nicely.

```
if (!strcmp(__BASE_FILE__, __FILE__)) {
    // works.
}
```

but you can't define new main functions or use other preprocessor tricks. but you could short-circuit main by using static methods, but that's harsh and dirty.

But maybe you shouldn't do it. in Ruby/python, this works because usage of files is done at runtime. in C, all files are to be compiled to be used.

Keep in mind that most build system will build one file at a time, building them as object files, and rebuilding them only when necessary. So

```
 __BASE_FILE__ and __FILE__
```

will be equals most of the time in sources files, if not always. And i would strongly discourage you to do this in header files.

It's easier to just put your tests in separate files, only linking them when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, as others say, you're misusing it since you can't compare strings that way in C, and especially not in the preprocessor.

The file that defines `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` is the main file. There can be only one such function in an executable.

Comment: You might want to clarify "Yes - you are misusing the C preprocessor."

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said (you can't have the C preprocessor compare strings), be careful with `__BASE_FILE__` because it may not correspond to your definition of "main" file. `__BASE_FILE__` is the name of the file being compiled, so it's always equal to `__FILE__` in source files, and only differs in headers and other included files.

In particular, `__BASE_FILE__` is not the name of the file which contains the `main()` function.

Comment: This is actually What I wanted. I wanted to know if current file is the one beeing compiled.